# Custom lint check: identify generic on expression call

Tags: kotlin, lint, android-lint

I'm trying to write a lint check, that visits call expressions, and report on some violation based on a generic type.

To make it more clear, let's say I have this code:

```kotlin
object Foo {
    inline fun <reified T> bar() = T::class.java
}
```

And let's say that I want to write a lint check that complains when I call the `bar` method with `Int` as the generic type, but accept everything else.

So, with the following code, the second call to bar should trigger a warning:

```kotlin
object Whatever {
    fun someMethod() {
        val stringClass = Foo.bar<String>() // Should not complain

        val intClass = Foo.bar<Int>() // Should raise a warning
    }
}
```

How would one implement that? This is of course not the real use case, and what I'm really trying to do is have a proper detection of `bar<Int>`.

So far, this is what I have:

```
class MyDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {
    companion object Issues {
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
            id = "IntBarTest",
            briefDescription = "You used bar with an Int type!",
            explanation = "Explanation",
            category = Category.CORRECTNESS,
            severity = FATAL,
            implementation = Implementation(MyDetector::class.java, Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE)
        )
    }

    override fun getApplicableUastTypes() = listOf(UCallExpression::class.java)

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext): UElementHandler {
        return GenericTypeHandler(context)
    }

    inner class GenericTypeHandler(val context: JavaContext) : UElementHandler() {
        override fun visitCallExpression(node: UCallExpression) {
            if (isCallExpressionAnIntBar(node)) {
                context.report(ISSUE,
                    context.getNameLocation(node),
                    "Oh no, I should not use bar<Int>")
            }
        }

        private fun isCallExpressionAnIntBar(node: UCallExpression): Boolean {
            return if ("bar".equals(node.methodName) ||
                "Foo" == (node.receiverType as? PsiClassReferenceType)?.resolve()?.qualifiedName) {
                // We know it's the method we are looking for but now we must identify the generic
                TODO("Identify the generic")
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a big TODO :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually quite simple:

The UCallExpression exposes type arguments. So you simply have to do the following:

```kotlin
private fun isCallExpressionAnIntBar(node: UCallExpression): Boolean {
    return if ("bar".equals(node.methodName) ||
        "Foo" == (node.receiverType as? PsiClassReferenceType)?.resolve()?.qualifiedName) {
        // We know it's the method we are looking for but now we must identify the generic
        node.typeArguments.getOrNull(0)?.canonicalText == Int::class.qualifiedName
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

The reason it eluded me was that I'm developing with tests, and breakpoints in the detector. But my test code was wrong (didn't define properly dependencies and so on), and so the detector would of course not work properly: my object's type arguments was an empty array.

Once I fixed my test setup, `typeArguments` properly reported the the generic type.

Comment: Side not, probably cleaner to write `"Foo" == node.receiverType?.canonicalText` instead of `"Foo" == (node.receiverType as? PsiClassReferenceType)?.resolve()?.qualifiedName`